# Wordpress content templates for pages?

Tags: wordpress, layout, wordpress-theming

Is it possible to define a wordpress template with multilpe input areas for content? If yes, how?

The template will be for a local club with multiple groups like a soccer and a pingpong group. The layout for all groups should be the same and template based e.g. a group title at the top, followed by a group picture than the the age of members, group description and the group leaders and a list of events and blog entries in the side bar. The group manager should not be able to change the layout of a group-page. If I put the whole group description into one content-block the group admins can individually fill the content-block, which I want to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest looking into a Wordpress plug-in like this one:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cimy-user-extra-fields/

As far as breaking it down into Group Admins, that will require more coding.

Comment: Yes, coding is too much work. I guess the easiest solution is to work with a template plugin. However this means if changes are made later the existing pages must be changed manually to fit the new stile.